# re.match return match object only if pattern is not inside escaped string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get a match object only if the pattern is not inside escaped string?
For example given the string:

```
'my string \"string string inside of escaped string\" string string'
```

How can I ignore any substrings inside of the escaped string:

```
\"string inside of escaped string\"
```

and only get matches from the substrings not included in the escaped string?

E.G:

```
myString = 'my string string \"string inside of escaped string\" string string'

find_matches_not_escaped(myString)
```

returns

```
['mystring', 'mystring', 'mystring', 'mystring']
```

get 4 matches and not 6? (i.e ignoring the matches inside of the escaped string.)

Comment: `\"` is still `"`. They're just **quotes**. If you want remove all the things inside quotes with RegEx, you could try: `re.sub( ".+?" , ' ')`.

Comment: I know but I prefer to use double quotes where possible so its become a habit to escape them, I just used single quotes here to make it easier to understand the question.

Comment: But they're still quotes, e.g: `"string \" string \" string".replace('"', 'and')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a first pass to remove the internal quoted string, then search what remains:

```
>>> strippedstring = re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', '', myString)
>>> re.findall(r"\bstring", strippedstring)
['string', 'string', 'string', 'string']
```

Add a second round to remove single-quotes if that's needed. If the actual surrounding quotes are needed (they could affect word boundaries or the like), make the replacement string `'""'` so the quotes stay, but the contents are removed.

Another approach that allows you to mutate the matches while still reconstructing the original string is to split on the quoted text (with capture, to avoid losing it), mutate the even indices in the result (unquoted text), then join it back together:

```
import itertools

# Puts the quoted strings in the odd indices and the unquoted in the even
splitstr = re.split(r'("[^"]*")', myString)

# Process only the even indices
for i, x in itertools.islice(enumerate(splitstr), None, None, 2):
    splitstr[i] = re.sub(r'\bstring', 'foo', x)

# Put it all back together and print
newstring = ''.join(splitstr)
print(newstring)
```

which outputs:

> my foo foo "string inside of escaped string" foo foo

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to ignore the text inside of the quotes I can't remove them.

Comment: @Mango: Why not? The original string remains unmodified here, so you haven't lost any data, we're just making a temporary stripped string to remove the stuff we don't care about.

Comment: Because I must modify the matches I've found, if I remove the text inside the quotes then the output will be incorrect.

Comment: Would it be possible to grab the position of the match I need and modify that using RegEx?

Comment: @Mango: I gave an example of how you could preserve the contents of the quoted strings while mutating the unquoted data. It's a bit more involved, but still less ugly than trying to make a regex that does all the work at once.

Comment: Thank you, with a little tinkering I got the expected output.